# Getting streaming to work properly in JWPlayer

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, jwplayer

I'm trying to implement streaming with JWPlayer using the following URL: rtmp://stream.technolutions.com/vod/mp4:0447d67935584a81986a0311443a7d9c.mp4.
I'm putting this RTMP URL in the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("modal-videoplayer-container-1").setup({
        file: "rtmp://stream.technolutions.com/vod/mp4:0447d67935584a81986a0311443a7d9c.mp4",
            image: "http://placehold.it/739x554/0000cc/&text=700x450",
        width: 700,
        height: 450
    });
</script>
```

I understand there's a different between Application and Stream but testing this URL inside VLC as a remote video works just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer Yeah, sure. http://yale-preview.adoptive.co/content_videos.html The last 2 videos are attempts to get 2 different streams to work. The first is being done by jquery plugin I wrote and the second is inline JS, copy/pasted from JW Player Docs.

Comment: It looks like your jw player flash swf file didn't get uploaded properly, going to the url directly results in a white page - http://yale-preview.adoptive.co/scripts/vendor/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer, turns out that you are correct. Your support guy Cooper, who is top-notch, helped me figure it out. The solution to this was to use the cloud-hosted version of the JWPlayer so it will never get corrupted again.

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it. Yeah, Cooper is great :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are having similar problems it is possible that your SWF file could be corrupted (due to being moved/copied in an automated workflow such as Grunt or Gulp). Some aspects of JWPlayer may work but when you use a feature that's solely flash based (such as JWPlayer streaming) it will just show a blank black box where you expect your video to play.

Try including JWPlayer's cloud-hosted JS file instead of hosting it yourself to see if it solves it. Special thanks to Ethan and Cooper at JWPlayer for helping me out with this.